# How to hide elements out of div bounds

Tags: html, css, hide

At the beginning I want to say that I just study frontend so I need to help with something.

I want to prepare some tab slider.
I have something in left and right so my tab slider will be on center.

My tab slider have two buttons: <  and > (slide to left; slide to right).

In my tab slider are a lot of elements which sum of widths exceeds a max-width of parent div (it has "content" class).

I want to hide all elements which are out of parent div bounds so I try to use

> overflow: hidden;

but unfortunately those elements fell to second row.

```css
div.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

div.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.left,
div.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: green;
}

div.flex {
  display: flex;
}

ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="left">something in left</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="flex">
      <i><</i>
      <ul>
        <li>i-1</li>
        <li>i-2</li>
        <li>i-3</li>
        <li>i-4</li>
        <li>i-5</li>
        <li>i-6</li>
        <li>i-7</li>
        <li>i-8</li>
        <li>i-9</li>
        <li>i-10</li>
        <li>i-11</li>
        <li>i-12</li>
        <li>i-13</li>
        <li>i-14</li>
        <li>i-15</li>
        <li>i-16</li>
      </ul>
      <i>></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">something in right</div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I expect that if I use overflow and max-height my exceeds elements will be hide (on right - on one row) and not will be fall to second row.

[There is my example.](http://jsfiddle.net/y0zq1ne8/3/)

Will you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `white-space: nowrap` in `.flex` so that all items remains in the same line

```css
div.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

div.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.left,
div.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: green;
}

div.flex {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30px;
}

.flex i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.flex i.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.flex i.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="left">something in left</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="flex">
      <i class="prev"><</i>
      <ul>
        <li>i-1</li>
        <li>i-2</li>
        <li>i-3</li>
        <li>i-4</li>
        <li>i-5</li>
        <li>i-6</li>
        <li>i-7</li>
        <li>i-8</li>
        <li>i-9</li>
        <li>i-10</li>
        <li>i-11</li>
        <li>i-12</li>
      </ul>
      <i class="next">></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">something in right</div>
</div>
```